# Oracle using wrong index for select query?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

So I have a table with two indexes:

Index_1: Column_A, Column_B

Index_2: Column A, Column_B, Column_C

I am running a select query:

```
select * from table Where (Column A, Column_B, Column_C) 
IN(('1','2','3'), ('4','5','6'),...);
```

When using "EXPLAIN PLAN for" in SQL developer. It seems to be using the first index instead of the second, despite the second matching the values in my query?

Why is this? and is it hindering my optimal performance?

Comment: We can't really say without seeing the plan or knowing anything about the data.  If Oracle has good statistics for the target table, however, then it is probably choosing the most efficient plan.  That might easily rely on the two-column index in the very plausible event that the three-column index is a lot larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, although we can't analyze Oracle's query planning without knowing anything about the data or seeing the actual plan, the three-column index is not necessarily better suited for your query than is the two-column index, at least if the base table has additional columns (which you are selecting) beyond those three.

Oracle is going to need to read the base table anyway to get the other columns.  Supposing that the values in `column_C` are not too correlated with the values in `column_A` and `column_B`, the three-column index will be a lot larger than the two-column index.  Using the two-column index may therefore involve reading fewer blocks overall, especially if that index is relatively selective.

Oracle has a very good query planner.  If it has good table statistics to work with then it is probably choosing a good plan.  Even without good statistics it will probably do a fine job for a query as simple as yours.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, Oracle use an index with 2 columns as per explain plan, while my query involves selection of 20 columns from the table and where clause having 5 values as below:

```
from tab1
where Col1= 'A'
    and col2 = 'b'
    and col3 = 'c'
    and col4 = 'd'
    and col5 >= 10

Index1: col1, col2
Index2: col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
```

If I added a hint to use `index2` the query executed much faster than using `index1`... what could be done so that Oracle choose the `index2`?

Tried to ensure statistics are gathered, still system detects the `index1` as the best to use.

Comment: you need display code as code rather than text which will make more impact. Also you should provide for resource link for your claim. Also this is more confused explanation. Is this an answer or you are seeking answer?